# Wrapping S3 classes using S7

Tags: r, oop

I am trying to use the new S7 OOP being introduced to R (https://github.com/RConsortium/S7). I would like to use S7 to wrap an S3 method for the unary operator `|`.

I have an object of class `"ggsurvfit"`, and I would like to define three new methods:

```r
`|`(ggsurvfit, ggsurvfit)
`|`(ggsurvfit, ggplot)
`|`(ggplot, ggsurvfit)
```

A couple of weeks ago I was lucky enough to be in the same room with Hadley Wickham (who is part of the R Consortium team developing S7) and he kindly provided me the code below to wrap the S3 method using S7. (I added the returned text string FYI)

```r
method(`|`, list(new_S3_class("ggsurvfit"), new_S3_class("ggsurvfit"))) <- function(e1, e2) { 
  "This is ggsurvfit|ggsurvfit"
}
method(`|`, list(new_S3_class("ggsurvfit"), new_S3_class("ggplot"))) <- function(e1, e2) { 
  "This is ggsurvfit|ggplot"
}
method(`|`, list(new_S3_class("ggplot"), new_S3_class("ggsurvfit"))) <- function(e1, e2) { 
  "This is ggplot|ggsurvfit"
}
```

The issue I am having is that I can't get these methods to be initiated/triggered. In the example below, I was hoping/expecting the operation to return the string `"This is ggsurvfit|ggplot"`. What am I missing here? THANK YOU!

```r
library(ggsurvfit)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

S7::method(`|`, list(S7::new_S3_class("ggsurvfit"), S7::new_S3_class("ggplot"))) <- function(e1, e2) { 
  "This is ggsurvfit|ggplot"
}

plot1 <- 
  survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = df_lung) |> 
  ggsurvfit() +
  add_risktable()
class(plot1)
#> [1] "ggsurvfit" "gg"        "ggplot"

plot2 <- 
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) +
  geom_point()
class(plot2)
#> [1] "gg"     "ggplot"

ret <- plot1 | plot2
#> Error in plot1 | plot2: operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hmm `plot1 | plot2` works, and `{assign('ret', plot1 | plot2); ret}` also works. Risktable not shown, though.

Comment: I think the problem is that `|` is not an S7 method, and "ggsurvfit" is not an S7 class. The docs say about `method<-` that "_this is not a general method registration function: at least one of generic and signature needs to be from S7_". Wrapping an existing S3 class in `new_S3_class` does not make it an S7 class - it just declares that a class you want to use is S3.

Comment: @jay.sf I don't think it does - maybe you have `patchwork` loaded?

Comment: @AllanCameron Yeah, `ggsurvfit` imports that stuff, against this we are pretty powerless I guess.

Comment: Ah, yes there is a ggplot method from patchwork that is also working in the background. My ultimate goal is do a little processing of the ggsurvfit object (ie adding the risktable), and then use patchwork to place the figures side by side.

Comment: Ahhh @AllanCameron, this is very helpful. I was assuming that since ggplot was never going to be made into an S7 that the same held true for the ggsurvfit class and didn't need to declare anything as an S7 class. I'll play around with this more, but it sounds like it I make ggsurvfit an S7 class, then this code could work? (Because the signature would be S7 while the generic is not)

Comment: One part that will likely need tweaking is `new_S3_class("ggsurvfit")`. It's strange to me that the suggestion was to use this code, when I would be taking advantage of the S7 nature of ggsurvfit....anyway, more reading and testing to do, certainly.

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg if you rewrite ggsurvfit as an S7 class, your code should work as expected (see below). You just can't define non-S7 methods with (only) non-S7 classes

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg Pleasure to have helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that `|` is not an S7 method, and `"ggsurvfit"` is not an S7 class. The docs say about `method<-` that

> *this is not a general method registration function: at least one of generic and signature needs to be from S7*.

Wrapping an existing S3 class in `new_S3_class` does not make it an S7 class - it just declares that a class you want to use is S3. Since you probably don't want to make `|` an S7 generic, your best option may be to wrap your ggsurvfit in an S7 class. This seems to do the trick:

```r
library(S7)
library(ggsurvfit)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

ggsurvfit_S7 <- new_class("ggsurvfit_S7",
                   properties = list(
                     obj = new_S3_class("ggsurvfit")
                   )
)

method(`|`, list(ggsurvfit_S7, new_S3_class("ggplot"))) <- function(e1, e2) { 
  "This is ggsurvfit|ggplot"
}

method(`|`, list(new_S3_class("ggplot"), ggsurvfit_S7)) <- function(e1, e2) { 
  "This is ggplot|ggsurvfit"
}

method(`|`, list(ggsurvfit_S7, ggsurvfit_S7)) <- function(e1, e2) { 
  "This is ggsurvfit|ggsurvfit"
}
```

Of course, you will need to create the `ggsurvfit` in the wrapper for this example. In production you would likely rewrite ggsurvfit to *be* an S7 class, but this gives you the idea:

```r
plot1 <- ggsurvfit_S7(
  obj = survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = df_lung) |> 
        ggsurvfit() +
        add_risktable()
  )

plot2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) + geom_point()
```

But the correct behaviour is observed:

```r
plot1 | plot2
#> [1] "This is ggsurvfit|ggplot"

plot2 | plot1
#> [1] "This is ggplot|ggsurvfit"

plot1 | plot1
#> [1] "This is ggsurvfit|ggsurvfit"
```

Of course, you will need to define a `print` method for your wrapper, but this seems very straightforward in S7

```r
method(print, ggsurvfit_S7) <- function(x, ...) print(x@obj, ...)

plot1
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to work through this! This solution is beautiful. I re-write and re-release `ggsurvfit()` as S7 in the next release of the package. MUCH APPRECIATED ('-'*)

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg I look forward to it - a great package.